# Decode function inside a decode function in SQL

Tags: sql, decode

What does the sql statement below print with explanation please:

```
SELECT DECODE (2, 2, DECODE(3, 7, 2, 4, 5, 6)) FROM DUAL
```

I understand the decode function alone but wanted to make sure of my answer of a decode inside a decode function

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=505f60c79e09b90f6f7e92ae4045e20c

Comment: If you don't understand what you've been taught, *talk* to your tutor/advisor about it. They'll a) know what you've been taught and b) maybe revise their materials. Asking strangers to do your homework doesn't, *actually* help you or others.

Comment: Santander would not be happy mate :')))

Answer (score 3):

It prints a 6.

The syntax is DECODE( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [, default] )

```
In your example 
    In the first DECODE 2 is the expression
    the next 2 is what the first 2 will be compared to
    the next DECODE is the result if 2 = 2

    In the second DECODE 3 is the expression
    It is compared to the 7 and the 4.
    The results could be 2 or 5
    Finally if the 3 doesn't match the 7 or the 4 then 6 is the result.
```

```
IF 2 = 2 THEN
  IF 3 = 7 THEN 
    2
  ELSIF 3 = 4 THEN
    5
  ELSE 6
END IF
```

Answer (score 1):

In general,
DECODE(expression, value/false, 
                value/true)

This is exactly like
               IIF(expression ,value, true, false)

```
        IIF(2=2,     
                  - -TRUE
         IIF(3=7, 2,  - - 2 is true
               , IIF(3=4, 5,  - - 5 is true
                 6)) - - false)
          , 2)
```

Decode is used over IIF because it more or less reduces the code.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the query

`SELECT DECODE (2,2,DECODE(3,7,2,4,5,6)) FROM DUAL`

you need to understand the decode function.

From http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0300__Conversion-Functions/UsingtheDECODEFunction.htm

> DECODE(value, search_value, result, default_value) compares value with search_value. If the values are equal, DECODE() returns result, otherwise default_value is returned. DECODE() allows you to perform if-then-else logic in SQL without having to use PL/SQL.

Even better might be https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-comparison-functions/oracle-decode/ with some explicit examples for if/then/else.

The result is 6.

Answer (score 0):

Decode syntax can be looked as following

DECODE( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [, default] )

Now put your values here:
In your case expression is : 2
search is : 2

expression matched with search so result is **DECODE(3,7,2,4,5,6)**. As result is again a decode so same pattern will apply. But in this case there is no expression (3) and search match(7,4) so default value (6) will be picked.

Final result will be 6.

If you will remove 6 from second decode then NULL will be returned.